# Jetty: ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:215] - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, jetty, shibboleth

I installed and configured **Jetty 7** correcty for *IdP Shibboleth* following this guide: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPJetty7Prepare

But when i start Jetty by running this command:

```
java -jar start.jar jetty.port=26335
```

I get this following error:

```
12:16:51.494 - ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:215] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/home/fuiba/opt/shibboleth-idp//conf/internal.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-web-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92) ~[spring-web-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123) ~[spring-context-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422) ~[spring-context-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352) ~[spring-context-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255) ~[spring-web-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199) ~[spring-web-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45) [spring-web-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) [jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230) [jetty-deploy-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259) [jetty-xml-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_24]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182) [jetty-xml-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.getLastChild(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:87) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398) ~[spring-beans-2.5.6.SEC03.jar:2.5.6.SEC03]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Where i did wrong?
How can i include ElementTraversal?
Thank you for any help!

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a double slash? in this path you used -

/home/fuiba/opt/shibboleth-idp**//**conf/internal.xml

Comment: Thank you! I had already seen it but I don't know where to edit that path.

Comment: Issue this command and press enter as you go through the files -> grep '/home/fuiba/opt/shibboleth-idp//conf/internal.xml' /home/fuiba/opt/ | less

Comment: This will allow you to locate the file containing that path. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. But I get many of `~` and `(END)`. I think that grep doesn't found the file that contains `/home/fuiba/opt/shibboleth-idp//conf/internal.xml`.

Comment: Opps! Sorry, I forgot the -r -> try this, grep -r '/home/fuiba/opt/shibboleth-idp//conf/internal.xml' /home/fuiba/opt/*